# Accessing managed object by objectID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have three contexts:

```
masterMOC - private queue tied to the persistent store, so physical saves happen here
----mainMOC - main queue tied to the UI, child of masterMOC
-------backgroundMOC - private queue, child of mainMOC
```

Let's see I create an Employee object on the `mainMOC`, then save the `mainMOC`. Then I save the `masterMOC` (which writes to disk).

Now, I've saved the Employee `NSManagedObjectID` in a variable, objectID. I want to get this Employee on the backgroundMOC. Does `[backgroundMOC objectWithId:objectID]` serve this purpose? Will it go to the persistent store and fetch this object using that method? Or will I have to preform a fetch request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your'e doing it right. They want you to pass objects between MOContexts using ID's. objectWithId will hit the persistent store and load the object in a fresh state. 
The only gotcha you have to worry about is this case.

You fetch an object or create a new object in a MOContext. 
You try pass the objectID to another context WITHOUT SAVING
The new MOContext wont know about the updates, and if you created a new object the objectID wouldn't be in the persistent store, so I think it returns nil or it's not defined.

Comment: Actually after doing some more research, I think objectWithId doesn't hit the persistent store, and only gets the object if it was once loaded into the context. existingObjectWithId, on the other hand, does hit the store.

Comment: Actually it says it might fetch or return a faulted object. So either way you should be safe as long as it's a valid ID
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html

Comment: The difference between objectWithId and existingObjectWithId should only be that objectWithId assumes the object exists and may fault it. existingObjectWithId never returns a fault and handles gracefully the cases where your object with given objectId does not exist. Otherwise they should act similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WWDC video from this year titled 'Core Data Best Practices' that talks about nested MOC's. But to answer your question, yes, `objectWithId` will travel up through the fewest number of MOC levels to find the object. So if you call `[backgroundMOC objectWithId:objectID]` and the object exists in the `mainMOC`, it will get it from the `mainMOC` without having to go all the way to the `masterMOC` or the database.